# Capture Screen while animating

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, screen-capture

I need to capture view while it is animating. Following code i am using to capture image while animation.

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.10 target: self selector:@selector(captureImage:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

UIImage * toImage = [[AppDelegateObj resultedImageArray]objectAtIndex:1];

[UIView transitionWithView:beforeImgView 
duration:5 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
animations:^{ 
beforeImgView.image = toImage;
} 
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
[myTimer invalidate];
}];
}

-(void)captureImage:(NSTimer*) t {
    CALayer *layer;
    layer = [self.view.layer presentationLayer];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),self.view.frame);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

It only captures resultant image

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy of the view which has animating objects and use that copy view for capturing the screen. i.e.

```
UIView *copyView = [self.view mutableCopy];

CALayer *layer;
layer = [copyView.layer presentationLayer];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),copyView.frame);
[layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Its is crashing with error- 
-[UIView mutableCopyWithZone:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: After replacing 1st line of your code with 
NSData *tempArchiveView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.view];
    UIView *copyView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchiveView];

blank screens are saved in photo library

Comment: UIView doesn't implement the copy method.

Comment: any solution for the problem?

Comment: Hey , you can use this line of code for coping a UIView object        
 

UIView *copyView =    [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.view]];

Comment: @Anuj: I used that piece of code, then the resultant image captured was a blank image.

Comment: the another thing you can do is create a new view at the time you want to capture self.view. what you have to do at that time is get the animating objects frames data from self.view  and  use this data to create a new view with all those objects  for snapshot